# Way to Search SQL DB based off 19 user inputs html

Tags: html, sql

I have code below that is a basic web page that allows a user to search a DB and return all values that match into one cell delimited with either a , or ;. What my issue is though right now it does a like search so if for instance i put "le" in the street it would pull up LEE,NOBLE and whatever else. Which is kind of fine for a search. What I would like to do is have another search that is exact match based off what fields the user inputs. The user should still be able to enter a value into any of the 19 inputs. So if i put in just "LEE" it would show just "LEE" in the street name but in the city boxes could have multiple entries as it returns all cities with a street named lee seperated by the delimiter. if the customer entered "LEE" into street and "PHILADELPHIA" into CITY. It would for instance list all the DIVISIONS on "LEE" in "PHILADELPHIA" Seperated by the delimiter

I am not very knowledgable about this stuff and was asked for this. I have googled a lot to get to this point where it returns based off partial inputs. Ban exact search is more beneficial though as some of the data is very similar and may have only 1 letter or number difference at the end

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/background.css">
 <body>

<form action="" method="post">

 <input name="streetsearch" placeholder="street" type="search" autofocus>
 <input name="ksearch" placeholder="K"type="search">
 <input name="carsearch" placeholder="CARS" type="search">
 <input name="ctsearch" placeholder="CT" type="search">
 <input name="divisionsearch" placeholder="DIVISION" type="search">
 <input name="SYSTEMtemsearch" placeholder="SYSTEMTEM" type="search">
 <input name="personsearch" placeholder="PERSON" type="search">
 <input name="vidsearch" placeholder="VID" type="search">
 <input name="zipsearch" placeholder="ZIP" type="search">
 <input name="citysearch" placeholder="CITY" type="search">
 <input name="statesearch" placeholder="STATE" type="search">
 <input name="billsearch" placeholder="BILL" type="search">
 <input name="namesearch" placeholder="Name" type="search">
 <input name="siteidsearch" placeholder="SITE ID" type="search">
 <input name="altidsearch" placeholder="ALT ID" type="search">
 <input name="uspscitysearch" placeholder="USPS CITY" type="search">
 <input name="countysearch" placeholder="County" type="search">
 <input name="idsearch" placeholder="ID" type="search">
 <input name="SYSTEMtemsearch" placeholder="SYSTEMTEM or TIMEZONE" type="search">
 <input type="submit" name="button">

</form>

<table align="center" color="white" border="1px" width="100%" height="auto" style="table-layout:fixed" align="left; line-height:auto;">
  <tr>
            <th>street</th>
            <th>K</th>
            <th>CARS</th>
            <th>CT</th>
            <th>DIVISION</th>
            <th>SYSTEMTEM</th>
            <th>PERSON</th>
            <th>VID</th>
            <th>ZIP</th>
            <th>CITY</th>
            <th>STATE</th>
            <th>BILL</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>SITE ID</th>
            <th>ALT ID</th>
            <th>USPS CITIES</th>
            <th>COUNTY BY ZIP</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>SYSTEMTEM OR TIMEZONE</th>
        </tr>

<?php

$con=mysql_connect('localhost', '******_tabel', 'password');
$db=mysql_select_db('******_DB');


if(isset($_POST['button'])){    //trigger button click

    $searchstreet=$_POST['streetsearch'];
    $searchk=$_POST['ksearch'];
    $searchcar=$_POST['carsearch'];
    $searchct=$_POST['ctsearch'];
    $searchdivision=$_POST['divisionsearch'];
    $searchSYSTEMtem=$_POST['SYSTEMtemsearchsearch'];
    $searchperson=$_POST['personsearch'];
    $searchvid=$_POST['vidsearch'];
    $searchzip=$_POST['zipsearch'];
    $searchcity=$_POST['citysearch'];
    $searchstate=$_POST['statesearch'];
    $searchbill=$_POST['billsearch'];
    $searchname=$_POST['namesearch'];
    $searchsiteid=$_POST['siteidsearch'];
    $searchaltid=$_POST['altsearch'];
    $searchuspscity=$_POST['uspscitysearch'];
    $searchcounty=$_POST['countysearch'];
    $searchID=$_POST['IDsearch'];
    $searchSYSTEMtem=$_POST['SYSTEMtemsearch'];



  $query=mysql_query("select group_concat(distinct STREET order by STREET) as STREET, group_concat(distinct K order by K) as K, group_concat(distinct CAR order by CAR) as CAR, 
  group_concat(distinct CT order by CT) as CT, group_concat(distinct DIVISION order by DIVISION) as DIVISION, group_concat(distinct SYSTEM order by SYSTEM) as SYSTEM, group_concat(distinct PERSON order by PERSON) as PERSON,
  group_concat(distinct VID order by VID) as VID, group_concat(distinct ZIP order by ZIP) as ZIP, group_concat(distinct CITY order by CITY SEPARATOR ';') as CITY, 
  group_concat(distinct STATE order by STATE SEPARATOR ';') as STATE, group_concat(distinct BILL order by BILL) as BILL, group_concat(distinct NAME order by NAME) as NAME,
  group_concat(distinct SITEID order by SITEID) as SITEID, group_concat(distinct ALTHUB order by ALTHUB) as ALTHUB, group_concat(distinct USPSCITIES order by USPSCITIES SEPARATOR ';') as USPSCITIES,
  group_concat(distinct COUNTYBYZIP order by COUNTYBYZIP) as COUNTYBYZIP, group_concat(distinct ID order by ID) as ID, group_concat(distinct SYSTEMTEMORTIMEZONE order by SYSTEMTEMORTIMEZONE) as SYSTEMTEMORTIMEZONE
  from TABLE where STREET like '%{$searchSTREET}%' AND K like '%{$searchK}%' AND CAR like '%{$searchcarshe}%' AND CT like '%{$searchCT}%' 
  AND DIVISION like '%{$searchdivision}%' AND SYSTEM like '%{$searchSYSTEM}%' AND PERSON like '%{$searchPERSON}%' AND VID like '%{$searchvod}%' 
  AND ZIP like '%{$searchzip}%' AND CITY like '%{$searchcity}%' AND STATE like '%{$searchstate}%' AND BILL like '%{$searchBILL}%'
  AND NAME like '%{$searchNAME}%' AND SITEID like '%{$searchsiteid}%' AND ALTHUB like '%{$searchALTHUBID}%' AND USPSCITIES like '%{$searchuspscity}%'
  AND COUNTYBYZIP like '%{$searchcounty}%' AND ID like '%{$searchID}%' AND SYSTEMTEMORTIMEZONE like '%{$searchSYSTEMtem}%'LIMIT 1000");


if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {



  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['STREET']."</td><td>".$row['K']."</td><td>".$row['CAR']."</td><td>".$row['CT']."</td><td>".$row['DIVISION']."</td><td>".$row['SYSTEM']."</td><td>".$row['PERSON']."</td>
    <td>".$row['VID']."</td><td>".$row['ZIP']."</td><td>".$row['CITY']."</td><td>".$row['STATE']."</td><td>".$row['BILL']."</td><td>".$row['NAME']."</td><td>".$row['SITEID']."</td>
    <td>".$row['ALTHUB']."</td><td>".$row['USPSCITIES']."</td><td>".$row['COUNTYBYZIP']."</td><td>".$row['ID']."</td><td>".$row['SYSTEMTEMORTIMEZONE']."</td>
    </tr>";
  }
}else{
    echo "No DATA<br><br>";
  }

}else{                          //while not in use of search  returns all the values
  $query=mysql_query("select * from TABLE order by STATE LIMIT 1");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['STREET']."</td><td>".$row['K']."</td><td>".$row['IRIS/CARS HE']."</td><td>".$row['CT']."</td><td>".$row['DIVISION']."</td><td>".$row['SYSTEM']."</td><td>".$row['PERSON']."</td>
    <td>".$row['VOD BACKOFFICE']."</td><td>".$row['ZIP']."</td><td>".$row['CITY']."</td><td>".$row['STATE']."</td><td>".$row['BILL']."</td><td>".$row['HUB NAME']."</td><td>".$row['SITE ID/BU']."</td>
    <td>".$row['ALT HUB ID']."</td><td>".$row['USPS CITIES']."</td><td>".$row['COUNTY BY ZIP']."</td><td>".$row['HUB ID']."</td><td>".$row['SYSTEMTEM OR TIME ZONE']."</td></tr>";
  }
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

right now if enter "L" into street it returns with "L" in it. If i enter "LEE" it would return that as street but also potentially "LEE VIEW", "LEE CHURCH", and "LEEWAY". I would like it to be an exact search based off the user input.

Comment: Don't use LIKE because that is what it does, it finds things that are LIKE not EQUAL. Replace the LIKE with equal. where field = 'searchterm';

Comment: @NawedKhan So I just tried that. As soon as I change it from LIKE to = It won't work. it then requires every field to be entered not just one or a couple that the user knows.